# Ipad app link open in UIWebViews

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, hyperlink

I have an iPad app with to UIWebViews. Is there a way to have some of the links clicked in the top view open in the bottom view, based on an attribute of the link's html? (Such as target="" or id="")

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. You can listen to the UIWebViewDelegate Protocol for webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: and then decide if it should load there or if you want to send this to the other one.

If you really wanted this behavior you could parse the html yourself and use this delegate to route the request if it seems to be a link with target blank,etc.

It is not something easy and will probably lead to problems(since most of the internet is not xhtml).